# Calling org-update-statistics-cookies on the whole document

Tags: org-mode

I have an org file like this

```
* Fun stuff [0/0]
** TODO Task 1
** TODO Task 2
```

If I run `org-update-statistics-cookies` inside `[0/0]` or press `C-c C-#` the text get updated to `[0/2]`. However, I would like to update all statistics in the document. Is there a way to do this? I found that if I call `(org-update-checkbox-count t)` the whole document gets updated to count checkboxes but not tasks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The doc for the function states:

> Update the statistics cookie, either from TODO or from checkboxes.
>   This should be called with the cursor in a line with a statistics
>   cookie.  When called with a C-u prefix, update
>   all statistics cookies in the buffer.

So call it like this: `C-u M-x org-update-statistics-cookies RET` (or equivalently `C-u C-c #`).

Comment: The shortcut for this is `C-c #`.

Comment: Thanks - edited, but note that the `C-u` is necessary for this use case.

Comment: You're right! My mistake.